SSL certa sha changed, but Chrome still uses old one
I was forced to change ssl certificate for one from my domains. So, cert changed, sha256 changed. Old cert was not expired yet, but it's now replaced with new one.
But, it looks like Chrome does not want to refresh cert with new one. After click on address bar, open connection info, all info is still related to old cert, which does not exists anymore on server. When I hit Ctrl+F5, Chrome will show correct, new cert. But after I close Chrome, open it again and open my website next time, it still shows old certificate.
The same goes to mobile Chrome on Android. However, in private mode, Chrome always show new cert only, so I guess it keeps something cached.
Is that normal? Old cert will expire soon, will Chrome load only new, valid cert then?

Yes, this is a known behavior. Chrome sometimes caches SSL certificates, showing the old cert until it expires or the cache is cleared. Incognito mode always shows the new cert, as it bypasses the cache. After the old cert expires or the cache is cleared, Chrome will update to the new cert….To validate, use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to check your domain validity, if it shows as expected then you’re all good
